# Social authentication using passports js and angular 2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, passport.js

My angular 2 app runs in localhost:4200 and node api server runs in 8080 port. How can I pass the user data once user has successfully completed the single sign on request to the client app.

Passport JS code:

```
router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook',     {
  successRedirect: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4200/',
}));
```

Angular 2 code:

```
facebooklogin()
 var newWindow = window.open(`http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook`,'name', 'height=585, width=770');
   if (window.focus) {
   newWindow.focus();
 }


/* how can I get the passport session data here */


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do a redirect in the success case and add the information as query params.